# Electron - WinInstaller

Tags: node.js, windows-installer, electron

I try to create a windows installer for my elctron application but when I run the file I have this error:

```
spawn mono ENOENT
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! thermowell-design@1.2.0 installer-win: `npm run pack-win && node installers/windows/createinstaller.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the thermowell-design@1.2.0 installer-win script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

This is the `createinstaller.js` file:

```
const createWindowsInstaller = require('electron-winstaller').createWindowsInstaller
const path = require('path')

getInstallerConfig()
  .then(createWindowsInstaller)
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error.message || error)
    process.exit(1)
  })

function getInstallerConfig () {
  console.log('creating windows installer')
  const rootPath = path.join('./')
  const outPath = path.join(rootPath, 'release-builds')

  return Promise.resolve({
    appDirectory: path.join(outPath, 'Thermowell-Design-win32-x64/'),
    authors: 'Pippo',
    noMsi: true,
    outputDirectory: path.join(outPath, 'windows-installer'),
    exe: 'thermowell-design.exe',
    setupExe: 'thermowell-design-app.exe',
    setupIcon: path.join(rootPath, 'assets', 'images', 'icons', 'logo.ico')
  })
}
```

There are the dependencie version:

1. electron: 5.0.0-beta.2,
2. electron-packager: 13.0.1,
3. electron-winstaller: 2.7.0

end the `nodejs` version is `10.15.1`

Answer (score 2):

It's too late to answer but leaving it for somebody if they need it in future. I got the same problem and here are my fixes:

1. depending upon my project structure I changed rootPath = path.join(__dirname,'../..')
2. install mono from https://www.mono-project.com/download/stable/#download-lin-ubuntu
3. install wine from https://tecadmin.net/install-wine-on-ubuntu/
   The two installations are for non-windows platform if your building your installer for windows platform

Those were my fixes but here's another [link](https://github.com/electron/windows-installer/issues/236) that might be helpful for you.